# Unix script meaning required

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to run a script in unix. It's a simulation that I need to run for two different months. For that the following portion of the script is vital. Can anyone please tell what it means?

```
set JUL = $today:e
set CAL = $today:r
set YESTERDAY = `echo ${CAL} | awk '{printf("%2.2d",$1-1)}'`
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: As an assumption, JUL is short for Julian Calendar, and CAL is short for Gregorian Calender

Answer (score 5):

The snippet you provide is out of context, so it's difficult to say what it means in the larger scheme of what you are doing, but:

```
set JUL = $today:e
```

Creates a variable called `JUL` to the contents of the variable `$today`, using a tcsh or csh modifier (`:e`) to remove everything but the extension of `$today`.

```
set CAL = $today:r
```

Creates a variable called `CAL` to the contents of the variable `$today`, using a tcsh or csh modifier (`:r`) to remove the extension, but leaving the root name of `$today`

I'm guessing $today are log files specific to a certain time? or something like that.

The final line:

```
set YESTERDAY = `echo ${CAL} | awk '{printf("%2.2d",$1-1)}'`
```

creates the variable `YESTERDAY` to the results of echoing `$CAL`, and uses `awk` to print the digits contained in $CAL, minus 1 (resulting in, presumably, yesterday's date).